# Proper Dictionary naming in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

Let's say we have a dictionary: `[String: String]`

Where key is `id` and value is `name`

Is there a common convention or recommended way to name this dictionary?

What I currently stick to is:

```
let nameForId: [String: String]
```

Are there any problems with naming dictionaries that way?

Comment: IMHO, I would call it by the value it represents, so I would call it `names`. Refer https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: @user1046037 `names` sounds like it would be a `[String]`. "Include all the words needed to avoid ambiguity for a person reading code where the name is used."

Comment: Try to write questions that invite objective, factual answers rather than opinions. If you're just hoping for some assurance that your style is OK, ask in a chat room. Asking what we think will lead to discussion, perhaps even arguments, with no clearly correct answer; asking whether there's a standard for how to name things is more objective -- there either is, in which case someone can point you to it, or there isn't, which is also useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if there's a domain-specific term, I would use that. For example:

```swift
let addressBook: [Person: PhoneNumber]
```

Otherwise, I like the `valuesByKey` style. I'd suggest pluralizing `name`, like so:

```swift
let namesById: [String: String]
```

You could also use some `typealias`es to better capture some info into the type:

```swift
typealias Name = String
typealias ID = String

let names: [ID: Name]
```

However, type aliases really are just aliases. `Name`, `ID` and `String` are inter-operable, so that won't prevent you from accidentally passing an `ID` where a `Name` is expected, or vice-versa. If you'd like that, you could cook up some wrapper structs instead.